# How to add a number beside a paragraph?

Tags: numbering, paragraphs, sections-paragraphs

[image: number beside paragraph]

How to add a number like the "2:", besides the paragraph, so that the paragraph is still at the center of the page?

Comment: Sorry not so clear of what you're looking for. Add numbers like what by the way? You mean the number 2: ?

Comment: @shahrinaismail yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an implementation using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to set the appropriate numbering and indentation for a list that matches your output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\bfseries\arabic*:},ref=\arabic*,leftmargin=0pt}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={(\alph*)},labelindent=0pt,itemindent=2em,leftmargin=*,align=left}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ultricies placerat dignissim. 
In at purus elementum, sodales metus ut, gravida nulla. Proin dictum leo turpis, vitae posuere ante convallis quis. 
Aenean sodales luctus urna id maximus. Duis sed mauris finibus, dignissim diam ac, imperdiet odio. 

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  Maecenas ultricies placerat dignissim. 
  In at purus elementum, sodales metus ut, gravida nulla. 

  \item
  Proin dictum leo turpis, vitae posuere ante convallis quis. 
  Aenean sodales luctus urna id maximus. 
  Duis sed mauris finibus, dignissim diam ac, imperdiet odio. 

  \item
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
    Donec sed dolor at magna iaculis vestibulum rhoncus ac turpis. 
    Aliquam placerat leo bibendum, accumsan velit mattis, consequat purus. 

    \item
    Nullam efficitur vehicula magna, nec pharetra felis sollicitudin non. 
    Etiam tempus nec ex vitae tincidunt. 
    Morbi enim diam, vestibulum id ultricies id, commodo ut erat. 

    \item
    Integer quis urna vel ipsum dictum mattis vitae a enim.
  \end{enumerate}

  \item
  Proin at semper dui. Mauris ut aliquet ipsum, ut eleifend ex. 
  Nullam rhoncus, lectus id volutpat ornare, massa dui mattis nibh, 
  nec dictum risus velit eget elit. Ut laoreet tellus nisi, 
  hendrerit commodo mi eleifend vel.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

---

If you're not using a list-like structure within and you just want to number the paragraphs, you can tie into the `\par` *hook* using [`everyhook`](http://ctan.org/pkg/everypar):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{everyhook}

\newenvironment{numpars}
  {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No paragraph indent
   \setcounter{paragraph}{0}%
   \renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}}%
   \PushPreHook{par}{%
     \stepcounter{paragraph}%
     \llap{\bfseries\theparagraph: }}%
  }{}


\begin{document}

\noindent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ultricies placerat dignissim. 
In at purus elementum, sodales metus ut, gravida nulla. Proin dictum leo turpis, vitae posuere ante convallis quis. 
Aenean sodales luctus urna id maximus. Duis sed mauris finibus, dignissim diam ac, imperdiet odio. 

\begin{numpars}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  Maecenas ultricies placerat dignissim. 
  In at purus elementum, sodales metus ut, gravida nulla. 

  Proin dictum leo turpis, vitae posuere ante convallis quis. 
  Aenean sodales luctus urna id maximus. 
  Duis sed mauris finibus, dignissim diam ac, imperdiet odio. 

  Donec sed dolor at magna iaculis vestibulum rhoncus ac turpis. 
  Aliquam placerat leo bibendum, accumsan velit mattis, consequat purus. 

  Nullam efficitur vehicula magna, nec pharetra felis sollicitudin non. 
  Etiam tempus nec ex vitae tincidunt. 
  Morbi enim diam, vestibulum id ultricies id, commodo ut erat. 

  Integer quis urna vel ipsum dictum mattis vitae a enim.

  Proin at semper dui. Mauris ut aliquet ipsum, ut eleifend ex. 
  Nullam rhoncus, lectus id volutpat ornare, massa dui mattis nibh, 
  nec dictum risus velit eget elit. Ut laoreet tellus nisi, 
  hendrerit commodo mi eleifend vel.
\end{numpars}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item this is item a
\begin{enumerate}
     \item Second level item
     \item Second level item
\end{enumerate}
\item another item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, in this way the paragraph is at the centere. I am looking for something that can put the number before the \textwidth so that the number wont affect the width and position of the paragraph